# verifiable research statement

Tags: phd

UPDATE:
So, am I to understand there is no such thing as a "verified research statement" besides an actual "recommendation" ? I already have a sense of the department(s) and professor's in the target phd proram know me from some elementary classes (but not that familiar with my academic background/research etc...)

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I am planning on applying to graduate school (phd). However, before that I plan on talking with relevant professors at these schools, I would like to take a portfolio if research work I have done already. So, can I goto my current/previous professor to write/sign my research statement to PROVE/VALIDATE the contents of the research  which I did under them. Although course description/syllabus will have general statements about research, specifics can only come from the professor. I do not want to wait till recommendations for application to mention my research experience.  Questions are:

1. Is this the norm ?
2. If not, what is the alternative way?

Comment: So, am I to understand there is no such thing as a "verified research statement" besides an actual "recommendation" ? I already have a sense of the department(s) and professor's in the target phd program know me from some elementary classes (but not that familiar with my academic background/research etc...)

Comment: Not really, if you did a senior thesis and if there is a signed cover page, then I suppose you could include that with your application portfolio. But really, if you said you worked with Prof. X on project B, then if there is any doubt, we'll call up Prof. X and ask her.

Answer (score 8):

If you're just going to talk to professors ahead of the application, you don't need to bring a portfolio and certainly don't need to bring letters. That's just overkill.

Just come prepared to talk about your work. If you have any publications that came out of it, you could bring those. Or even a brief summary sheet.

Verification will come later when the letters of reference come in with your entire application package.

Use your early visits to get a sense of the departments and the faculty who might be enthusiastic about your project and possibly serve as a PI. You'll impress them most by being enthusiastic about your work, being able to articulate its importance without having to fumble through your briefcase for external validation, and being able to express great interest in working in that particular discipline with that particular department and PI.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karen. What is PI ? Secondly, do some departments have something where you can do "free" research without them/you committing to  PhD and if it worksout, we can start at some later stage (next semester/year). Obviously,  the professor has to agree it too...

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have recommendation letters at hand already, then some the items that seem to be helpful would be like:

1. mentioning any published research (conference papers, journal papers, etc.)
2. Research projects that are already finished and the professor can check out the results and outcome of the research him/herself.

However, note that a recommendation letter from your previous professor would be valuable.

Comment: Can a professor give you a recommendation letter in hand i.e. not the one they submit when you apply but something  which sums up your research etc.. ?

Comment: You can your professor for such a letter and let him/her know that all you need is a list of research areas covered under his/her supervision.